# How to implement click event in BaseActivity in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am implementing common header in all activity.I want to implement click event for header.can anybody tell how to implement click event in BaseActivity(Parent Activity) in android.I am getting reference in parent activity .Is it possible to implement click using  setOnClickListener in parent activity?

```
 txtHeading =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtHeading);
```

I want to implement click event for textview in parent activity

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually create some helper method on the parent activity

```
public void setHeaderOnClick(View.onClickListener clickListener){
    txtHeading =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtHeading);
    txtHeading.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
}
```

when on the fragment, you can use

```
((YourActivityName)getActivity()).setHeaderOnClick(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //method here

    }
});
```

hope it helps

Comment: The argument to the setHeaderOnClick() in the fragment should be a new View.OnClickListener(), right?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it like...
1.)in your header a xml in the textView set these properties.

```
android:clickable="true"
android:onClick="onClick"
```

2.) write the direct public void onClick() in your BaseActivity Like

```
public void onClick(View v){
        if(v.getId() == R.id.txtHeading){

        }
    }
```

it will working charm yes after doing these steps don't find your text view component in BaseActivity.